# Writing JSON file in Xamarin PCL

Tags: json, xamarin

As System.IO.File is not available in Xamarin PCL, I have heard that the only way out of the problem of writing JSON file is to use Streams. However, I haven't found a good link as in how to use them easily. Moreover, is this the only way out or is there anyother method available that can help me in writing output in a JSON format.

Comment: it depends on which PCL profile you're using.  However, you can use the PCLStorage plugin to provide File IO from within the PCL, or use XF's DependencyService to inject File IO methods from your platform project.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jason says, you can use PclStorage.
Otherwise you can use DependencyService and write your code in Platform specific projects.
You can take a look to this repo

[TestReadFile](https://github.com/acaliaro/TestReadFile)

This is something for Android

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(FilesImplementation))]
namespace TestReadFile.Droid
{
    public class FilesImplementation : IFiles
    {
        public FilesImplementation()
        {
        }


        public string ReadTextFile(string path, string fileName)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName))){
                string line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
                return line;
            }
        }

        private string creaFileName(string directory, string fileName) { 
            string path = RootDirectory();
            string file = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName);
            return file;
        }

        public void WriteTextFile(string path, string fileName, string stringToWrite)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName),false))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(stringToWrite);
                sw.Close();
            }
        }

        public string RootDirectory()
        {
            File path = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim);
            return path.AbsolutePath;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is PCL interface

```
public interface IFiles
{
    string ReadTextFile(string path, string fileName);
    void WriteTextFile(string path, string filename, string stringToWrite);
    string RootDirectory();
}
```